# Aspect around @annotation doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I have written logging mechanism that doesn't work. I use:

aspectjrt 1.7.3
aspectjweaver 1.7.3
spring 3.0.6

```
@Aspect
public class TimeLogger {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TimeLogger.class);

    //@Around("execution(* myMethod(..))")
    //@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(TimeLog)")
    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(mypackage.TimeLog)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {

        Method method = MethodSignature.class.cast(point.getSignature()).getMethod();

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object result = point.proceed();

        LOG.info("AAAAAAAAAAAAA");

        return result;
    }
}


@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface TimeLog {
    LogLevels logLevel() default LogLevels.DEBUG;
}


<bean id="execTimeLogger" class="mypackage2.TimeLogger">
</bean>
```

Problem is that this logs something

```
  //@Around("execution(* myMethod(..))")
```

and this doesn't work:

```
 //@Around(" execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(mypackage.TimeLog)")
```

That means that nothing is logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, that your annotation is not in `mypackage2` same as `TimeLogger` ?

What you can also try is to use:

```
@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(ann)")
public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point, TimeLog ann) throws Throwable {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Strange, when I annotate MyAPI methods and inject it into some component (I am using XML mappings) and the property is of MyAPI type then it doesnt work. When I annotate MyApiImpl methods it works but I can't check TimeLog debugLevel (which is DEBUG) becaouse method method.isAnnotationPresent(TimeLog.class) return false, and the method MyAPI.something is checked instead of MyApiImpl.something...